# how to see if id in array already exists in localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I have this function, it saves the request response in localStorage. but I would like that if the id already existed in the array it would not make the request again

```
getItemById(id) {
// return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`);
 return  this.cacheS.getOrSetCache(id, `StoreService_getItemById_${id}_${this.layout.emp.id}`,  this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`), 300000);
}

getOrSetCache(
id: any,
key: string,
request: Observable < any > ,
msToExpire = 3600000
): Observable < any > {
let cache: any = {};
const keyy = 'StoreService_getItemById_teste';
cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyy));

return (cache?.data && cache?.exp > Date.now()) ||
    (cache?.data && cache?.data.find(item => item.data.id === id)) ?
    of(cache.data) : request.pipe(
        tap(v => {
            let arr: any[] = [];
            let string = localStorage.getItem(keyy);
            if (string) arr = JSON.parse(string);

            arr.push({
                data: v,
                exp: Date.now() + msToExpire
            });
            localStorage.setItem(keyy, JSON.stringify(arr));
        })
    );
}
```

now as you can see in the image it is saving duplicate ids
[image]

I tried a few ways but without success, it seems that I can't map each item in the array
the `console.log(cache)`
[image]

Comment: What happens when you change `cache?.data.find(item => item.data.id === id)` to `!cache?.data.find(item => item.data.id === id)`?

Comment: also, does `cache` even have a `data` property? the way you access the cache in the callback vs outside of it is quite different.

Comment: @returns the error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
I put a console.log(cache) in the code and updated my question with an image of the answer in the console
there appears the array.data, but there are several arrays

Comment: So `cache` doesn't have a `data` property, hence the `undefined`. `cache` is the same as `arr` in the `tap` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **||** condition.  That is a reason your Api always calls whether you have data or not.Like in **Or condition** If your one condition is true from both  **(cache?.data && cache?.exp > Date. now()) || (cache?.data && cache?.data.find(item => item.data.id === id))** then you can get into  the **if** block.

Comment: I didn't understand very well how I could solve the question, even when it already has the same id in my array it executes the request, I put a console.log(cache) and updated the image of the question

Comment: I would have to take the || from the code?
can you give me an example?

Comment: can you  change || to &&

Comment: Also, Can you tell me if your "cache?.exp > Date.now()" then what you want to do you want to call your API  either you have data in localStorge or not?

Comment: the idea is that when you have the id of an item already saved in localstorage, don't make the request again and the cache.exp if the current time is equal to or greater than this timestamp, it removes it from the cache and makes the query again

Comment: I tried switching to the && operator and it didn't work, it still makes the request and saves it in localstorage

Comment: Then you have to put your code any online platform then  I will help you

Answer (score -1):

`localStorage` is `key => value` storage, for searching etc. is better `IndexedDB`.
Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API